# Numpy vectorized and unvectorized code results not matching for 3d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I am trying to refactor procedural code of a numpy 3d array into it's vectorized equivalent  and the results are not matching .

```
import numpy as np 
              
arr = np.empty((16,73,144))

boolArray = np.zeros((14,73,144)) 

for k in range(0,16): 
   for j in range(0,73): 
      for i in range(0,144): 
        if (k == 0):
            doSomething():
        else if (k == 15):
             doSomething():
        else:
         if (arr[k+1,j,i] == arr[k-1,j,i]): 
              boolArray[k,j,i] = True
```

The vectorized counterpart -

```
# isArrEqual is a boolean array of identical shape to boolArray 
isArrEqual = (arr[2:,:,:] == arr[0:-2,:,:])
```

In my real data I get 6000 true entries for the procedural code and no trues at all in the vectorized counterpart.

Where I am going wrong ?

Comment: `arr = np.empty(16,73,144)` should be `arr = np.empty((16,73,144))`. Same for `boolArray`

Comment: @Corralien Edited. Thanks for pointing out the error.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a mistake in your procedural code.
I believe it should be

```py
for k in range(1, 15):  # changed 14 to 15 
   for j in range(0,73): 
      for i in range(0,144): 
         if (arr[k+1,j,i] == arr[k-1,j,i]): 
              boolArray[k-1,j,i] = True  # changed k to k-1
```

I don't see any issues in the numpy code.

Comment: Am I allowed to make an edit to the question based on your answer?

Comment: But doesn't that solve your problem?

Comment: No it does not. So can I make an edit ?

Comment: Yes. please be precise with data types in arrays

Comment: @gansub, you still have issues in your procedural code. (`IndexError` for `k` = 14 + syntax errors, + you didn't changed `k` to `k - 1` in the last line)

Comment: I will delete the question then. If you can delete your answer I will delete my question